# Configure assemblies redirection for a Burn-based boostrapper

Tags: wix, burn

We're developing a Burn-based setup, with a custom UI.

The custom UI project uses .NET Framework 4.8.

We're trying to use AutoFac 6.3.

When run, the setup fails with the following exception:

"System.IO.FileLoadException
Message=Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)"

This happens because the bundle uses the Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces NuGet package version 6.0.0.0, while the AutoFac assembly references the Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces.dll version 1.0.0.0

How can we instruct the bootstrapper to redirect the Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces assemblies to version 6.0.0.0? Is there a burn.config file we could use for that, similar to the app.config files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[BootstrapperCore.config](https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/redistributables_and_install_checks/install_dotnet.html) is the app.config.

Comment: Is there a way to get this to leverage the automatically generated binding redirects for the UX application in the bundle?